# jquery autocomplete not working with JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-autocomplete

My PHP code return JSON data to jquery autocomplete but autocomplete not working

Jquery autocomplete

```
$("input#txtaddkey").autocomplete({
            source: "keyword.php",
                minLength: 2
        });
```

PHP code

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM o_keyword where keyword like '%" . $query . "%'"); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['keyword'] = $row['keyword'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

JSON data output

```
[{"id":"2","keyword":"Games"},{"id":"3","keyword":"Goa"}]
```

And while typing "Ga" I am getting empty li tag in front end.

Comment: Does your "keyword.php" actually return anything? Check with firegug ...

Comment: yes it returns [{"id":"2","keyword":"Games"},{"id":"3","keyword":"Goa"}]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From:

- http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

your JSON needs to contain `label` or `value` (or both). Change `keyword` to `value` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to be slightly modified.

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['value'] = $row['id'];
    $row_array['label'] = $row['keyword'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
```

echo json_encode($return_arr);

Now your json format will be

```
[{"value":"2","label":"Games"},{"value":"3","label":"Goa"}]
```