# jQuery autocomplete do not work with json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

If I call the php file as source is does not autocomplete, but if I use an array it works.

PHP

```
$query = mysql_query($req);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $results[] = array('login' => $row['login']);
    }

echo json_encode($results);

//[{"login":"lleal"},{"login":"mmoura"},{"login":"vmatos"},{"login":"csamante"}]
```

HTML

```
$( "#logine" ).autocomplete(
{
     source: 'loginsearch.php',
})
```

If I transform the json to an array like this, it works:

```
    var lista = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "loginsearch.php",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                lista.push(data.login);
            });
        }
    });   


$( "#logine" ).autocomplete(
{
     source: lista,
})
```

I just spent a whole day hitting my head at this, any ideas ?

Comment: does your echo statement return data?

Comment: oh and an extra comma in your JS `source: 'loginsearch.php',`...unless you have more code following it

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234455/jquery-autocomplete-not-working-with-json-data?rq=1 Go and find your answer there. Exactly the same, although you may need to change the output like `//[{"id":"1, "value":"lleal"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON have to contain the variables 'label' and 'value' for the autocomplete to work.

try

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $results[] = array('label' => $row['login'], 'value' => $row['login']);
    }
```

or whatever you like to display as value and label.